# Persistent camera drift after OnPause -> OnResume on android googlevr sdk 1.10.0

Tags: android, google-vr-sdk

Any time an activity is resumed after being paused, the view will start to drift.
This is reproducible every time I minimize the app and reopen it. Minimizing and reopening the `TreasureHunt` demo(GoogleVR SDK sample app) is the easiest way to preview this bug.I've been unable to fix the issue after a number of tries. Does anyone faces the Issue?
If I skip `GvrView.onPause` and `GvrView.OnResume` it doesnot happens.

Comment: Having the same issue with gvr sdk 1.0.3 for Unity. gvr sdk 0.9.1 does **not** have the issue.